# Is $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^3-1)$ isomorphic to $\mathbb Q[X]/(X^3+1)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $A = \mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^3-1)$.
>
> 1. Prove that $A$ is a direct product of two integral domain;
>
>    Is the ring $A$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^3+1)$? Justify your answer.

My idea:  For question 1, $$ x^3-1 = (x-1)(x^2+x+1),$$ so$$\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3-1) = \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x-1) × \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2+x+1).$$

For question 2, yes, $A$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3+1)$.

Is it correct?

Comment: What are these two integral domains in (a)?

Comment: @lord shark the unkown   $ Q[x]/(x-1)  × Q[x]/x^2+x+1$,,,this are two integral domain

Comment: And can these be expressed in a more convenient way?

Comment: For B some sort of justification might be in order... or are we to believe you on your word?

Comment: i don't know  ...can u elaborate  in  answer ? @ Lord Shark

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez,,,yes i was looking this problem  ,,but i don't  how to Justify  .... i just used my logic

Comment: What logic did you use?

Comment: $Q[X]/(X^3-1)$ and $Q[x]/x^3+1$   both are   are direct product of  two integral doain ,,,so both are isomorphics@ Mariano

Comment: Well, $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb R$ is also a product of two integral domains, and it is not isomorphic to $Q[X]/(X^3-1)$.

Comment: Note that $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x-1)$ and $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2+x+1)$ are in fact fields. Can you find which fields they are isomorphic to and are relatively easy? For $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x-1)$ it should be easy. For $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2+x+1)$, you may recall the relation between the minimal polynomial and the field extension.

Comment: Here's a hint for (2): if you plot the roots of $X^3 - 1$ and $X^3 + 1$ in the complex plane, where do they lie? Or in a slightly different direction: if $\alpha$ is a root of $X^3 - 1$, can you find a root of $X^3 + 1$ that is closely related to $\alpha$?